# Publish Java Swing Application on Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, java, packaging, ubuntu-sdk

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a VirtualBox in Windows 8.1 and now I want to install Ubuntu SDK in it using the following commands:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But, it shows error and does not install Ubuntu SDK. Please help.

I have Java Swing desktop app that I want to publish on Ubuntu Software Center under development tools. Using Ubuntu SDK, I am trying to create click app packaging so that I can upload it here: https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/

Comment: Can you help with the error message you get

Comment: The error i get is: Package ubuntu-sdk is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source. E: 'Ubuntu-sdk' has no installation candidate.

Comment: I have successfully installed Ubuntu SDK. Now, I want to create click app package for my already developed java swing app that has .jar launcher file and two dependent jar files. What is the way to create click package for this app. I will upload that on Ubuntu Software Center.